# Did Louis Tully's speech mean anything?

Tags: ghostbusters, language-explanation

In the first *Ghostbusters* movie, after Louis Tully is possessed by Vinz Clortho (the dog-creature), arrested, and handed over to the Ghostbusters, he says:

> "Gozer the Traveller, he will come in one of the pre-chosen forms. During the **rectification of the Vuldronaii**, the Traveller came as **a large and moving Torb**! Then, during **the third reconciliation of the last of the Meketrex Supplicants** they chose a new form for him... that of **a Giant Sloar**! Many **Shubs and Zuuls** knew what it was to be roasted in the depths of the Sloar that day I can tell you."

I know that Dan Aykroyd's [father](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1605298751) was a paranormal "expert", and [Dan actually believes in much of this stuff](http://www.phantomsandmonsters.com/2009/10/dan-aykroyds-belief-in-paranormal.html);  as I understand it, [he tried to keep at least some parts of the movie true to what people like his father believed about ghosts](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2009/10/26/ghostbusters-is-real.html).  This led me to wonder if anything that Louis says here is supposed to make sense, and whether any of the terms he is using predate the movie.  The terms in question are as follows:

- The rectification of the Vuldronaii
- A large and moving Torb (as opposed to a small and stationary Torb?)
- The third reconciliation of the last of the Meketrex supplicants
- A giant Sloar
- Shubs
- Zuuls

Do any of these words mean anything, or were they used simply because they sounded cool?

Comment: The rectification and 3rd reconciliation may be meant to suggest Middle Eastern religious sects which are now obscure and forgotten: There are lots of these but I think those particular names are made up for the film, as are the names of the demonic sounding Torg and Sloar.

Comment: Also, a small and stationary Torb is no use for putting the fear of Gozer into recalcitrant Vuldronaii.

Comment: Did it mean anything? No. It meant *everything*.

Comment: Sloar was an advertising mascot for a Zuulian cookie dough company.

Comment: None pre-date the movie, nearly all of them have been fleshed out in Ghostbusters EU in RPG, video games, comics, or sourcebooks, etc.

Answer (score 22):

I met Dan Ackroyd during a promo for his new booze venture. I asked him about Ghostbusters (and Blues Brothers). He said they were just names that

> "sounded right".

Answer (score 12):

I think the point of that monologue was to convey a sense of scale to the supernatural world in this universe. As well-versed in the occult as the Ghostbusters (especially Egon) are, it's clear that even with resources like Tobin's Spirit Guide at their disposal humanity knows almost nothing about the big picture, the actual history of the universe, and what insignificant part we play in it.

Every piece of it is a tiny glimpse at unfathomable layers of lore, with unknowns on top of unknowns. And this is just passing conversation coming from the mere pet of an entity that to us is godlike but which is apparently just one lowly agent of still more powerful beings we've never previously even seen hints of. Who chooses Gozer's forms, and for what purpose? It's genuinely Lovecraftian if you think about it, which makes Rick Moranis' brilliant comedic delivery even more hilarious.

Answer (score 0):

It's just gobbledygook that conveys the labyrinthine and incomprehensible background of the occult world that led to the latest infestation of ghosts. It's meant to be deliberately complicated and hilariously nerdy. The way Louis Tully is speaking is not unlike the way a 12-year-old D&D enthusiast would excitedly describe the origins of his 9th level fighter thief. It's very funny.

Comment: This is likely correct, but do you have any information about the origin of the names used?